# given a sequence converging to 0, show the series converge and that its value is a0.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble proving the following problem, and also I'm not exactly sure how to choose/arrange an's in order to show the given series, as suggested in the problem..
[image]

Comment: Take $a_n=\frac  1n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with

$\displaystyle \{a_{n}\}^{\infty }_{n=0}\rightarrow 0$

We now choose $\displaystyle x_{n} =a_{n} -a_{n+1}$

Let's look at the sum $\displaystyle \sum ^{\infty }_{i=0} x_{n}$

This is

$\displaystyle \sum ^{\infty }_{i=0} x_{n} =\sum ^{\infty }_{i=0} a_{n} -a_{n+1} =( a_{0} -a_{1}) +( a_{1} -a_{2}) +...+( a_{n} -a_{n+1}) +...$

We see that $\displaystyle a_{1} ,a_{2} ,...,a_{n} ,...$ cancel so we are left with

$\displaystyle \sum ^{\infty }_{i=0} x_{n} =a_{0}$

Now for the sequence, I would suggest you try to think of how it got in that form.

One way to get $\displaystyle n( n+1)$ in the denominator is when we for example

substract two fractions together $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+1} =\frac{n+1-n}{n( n+1)} =\frac{1}{n( n+1)}$.

Because we get this alternating sum, you can see that the first term

of the sequence $\displaystyle a_{n} =\frac{1}{n}$ is $\displaystyle a_{1} =\frac{1}{1} =1$ and the other terms cancel out

like in the first example.